# Save the date of today in a string

Tags: c, datetime, formatting

I want to save the date of today in a string and have the following code with the following output:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
  printf("%02d-%02d", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon + 1);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Output (for today, November the 5th):

```
05-11
```

What is the easiest way to save `05-11` in a string?

Comment: Are you aware of `sprintf()`? Why does it not help?

Comment: Use `strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [`strftime` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) (declared in "time.h"), which takes a variety of format specifiers (akin to those used in `printf`) to extract and format the various date and/or time fields of a `struct tm`.

In your case, you would use the `%d` and `%m` specifiers to get the (two-digit) day and month numbers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char StrDate[8];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    strftime(StrDate, sizeof(StrDate), "%d-%m", localtime(&t));
    printf("%s\n", StrDate);
    return 0;
}
```

You could even add the newline character to the `StrDate` buffer directly, by appending the `%n` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

I used `sprintf()` which worked fine for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
  char str[80];

  sprintf(str, "%02d-%02d", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon + 1);
  printf("%s", str);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I think that `snprintf` is better than `sprintf`

Comment: thank you for your comment @embedded4ever. I don't really either of those functions. Why do you think `snprintf` is better than `sprintf`?